# MongoDB Match $in on two different fields only when they are the same

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Running into some issues with mongoDB query construction. I have an array of user IDs that I want to use to fetch posts. However, I only want to return posts for discussions that were created by a user's friend (these IDs are stored in the array), and where that user that created the discussion is still 'participating' in the discussion.  For the first part, I can simply do an $in query:

```
UIDArray = ['1ab','2bc','3cd']
Posts.find({created_by: {$in: UIDArray}})
```

However, we want a query where the 'friend' (the user in the UID array) has created the discussion, but is also still participating. I initially thought of doing the following:

```
Discussions.find({created_by: {$in: UIDArray}, participating: {$in: UIDArray}})
```

Now this obviously doesn't work; since the UIDArray contains UIDs of all friends, it would erroneously return discussions that were created by friend **1ab** (who might have left the discussion and is therefore no longer stored in the participating array), but still has **2bc** participating.

How do I ensure that the query only returns discussions where the user that created it and is stored in the created_by field, is also still in the participating field, which is an array?

Comment: You can use the [$where](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#op._S_where) query operator to execute a Javascript function that compares the two fields.

Comment: Thank you, I was just looking into that. I assume you'd propose doing something along the lines of {$where: 'this.participating.includes(this.created_by)'}?  What are the performance implications of a $where query?

Comment: Something along those lines, yes.

I wouldn't expect it to be **too** performance heavy for something that simple, but mickl's proposed answer below would definitely be the more performant solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Aggregation Framework's `$match` with [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) to specify a condition which includes more than one field:

```
Discussions.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            $expr: {
                $and: [ 
                    { $in: [ "$created_by", ['1ab','2bc','3cd'] ] },
                    { $in: [ "$created_by", "$participating" ] }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Haven't ran in to `$expr` yet - very clean.